# Display none at the end of animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, object

I'm trying to make element dissapear at the end of animation but it doesn't work, can someone explain how to make exit animation with element dissappearing at the end of it?:

```
var test = document.getElementById("test");
test.addEventListener("click", displayOpacity);

function displayOpacity(event){
    event.target.style.animation = "changeOpacity 1s linear";
    if(event.target.style.opacity === 0){
        event.target.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.container .test {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00f;
  max-width: 500px;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes changeOpacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes changeOpacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="test" id="test">Custom Text</div>
    </div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Post your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because the `animation-fill-mode` is not being respected as you're overwriting it by setting the `animation` rule directly on the element itself.

To fix this change your JS code to add a class on the element, and put the `animation` rule in there, along with the required fill mode:

```js
var test = document.getElementById("test");
test.addEventListener("click", displayOpacity);

function displayOpacity(event) {
    this.classList.add('changeOpacity');
}
```

```css
.container .test {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 100px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #00f;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.changeOpacity {
    animation: changeOpacity 1s linear forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes changeOpacity {
    0% {  opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes changeOpacity {
    0% {  opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes changeOpacity {
    0% {  opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="test" class="test">
        Test
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have tagged `jQuery`, wouldn't be it easier to do it with `.fadeOut()`? The `display` attribute of the element is being set to `none` just after the animation has ended.

```js
$('#test').click(function(){
  $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'>Text</div>
```

Comment: It would be easier, but animation with CSS is far more reliable and smoother due to the fact that its hardware accelerated, whereas JS is not.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Agreed, but it's just a one possible approach to this case. If OP wouldn't tag `jQuery`, I wouldn't post it. Anyways, it's very friendly and simple solution, especially for beginners.

Comment: No worries, I only mentioned it as you seemed to be asking why you'd choose CSS over jQuery in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The animation time is 1 second

```
event.target.style.animation = "changeOpacity 1s linear";
```

so just make a timeout

```
setTimeout(function(){
    event.target.style.display = "none";
},1000)
```